# Adding the Mathematica tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed there is a [matlab](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matlab).
What do you think of adding the [mathematica](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematica) ?

There are [about one hundred](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/search?q=mathematica) questions that would be relevant.

I don't know if the admins have tools to "mass retag" questions. Otherwise I could do it by hand a small batch at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly, that is something we could do. However, I think we must remember to avoid questions specific to Mathematica. There is a [topic about it](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/are-how-do-i-do-x-in-y-programming-language-off-topic/126#126).
As for mass tagging, I am not sure if it's possible. I would have to check on that one.

Anyway, I've created a tag so feel free to use it. I've been thinking whether to use `wolfram`/`wolfram-language`, but `mathematica` is just fine.

Comment: Agreed, I think we need to avoid Mathematica-specific questions (that's a StackOverflow question), but if someone posts a question that contains Mathematica code, it would be nice to be able to tag the question as such.

Comment: Thank you for having pointed me to the specific discussion. I notice in the second answer a use case that could be mine: _"Here's my code for a Hilbert transformer which gives funny results for complex inputs. Please help me find where it's wrong"_ Do you confirm the author's conclusion _this might as well be here_? Or do you think such questions are off-topic and should be asked on a different SE site?